# How to loop over and put JSON objects in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am developing an application in javascript. Here is my PHP code:

```
events: [
foreach($requests as $request)
                {
                    if($request->accepted == 'yes') {
                echo 
                "{
                        id: ". $request->id . ",
                        start:'". $request->start . "',
                        end: '". $request->end . "',
                    },";
                    }
]
```

So basically I am taking only `id`, `start` and `end` elements of the object and echoing them as JSON in an array. How would I be able to do the same in javascript foreach loop considering that var requests is the object containing all the data?

NOTE that there is also other data in requests such as `price`, `status` in addition to `id`, `start`, `end` but I only want to use `id` , `start` and `end` to be included in my `events[]` array.

Answer (score 3):

try this (assuming that requests is the object array)

```
var events = requests.map(function(obj){
 return { id : obj.id, start : obj.start, end : obj.end }
})
```

> Can you please suggest what do I do incase i need to show only the
>   requests where id > 50? How do I use if statement here?

```
var events = requests.filter(function(){
  if (index >= 50 ) return false;
}).map(function(obj, index){
  return { id : obj.id, start : obj.start, end : obj.end }
});
```

Comment: will it include all the requests in the events array?

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest what do I do incase i need to show only the requests where id > 50? How do I use if statement here?

Comment: `if (index >= 50 ) return false;` would not help You to filter the array, but rather fills it with `false`s.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев I have edited the answer to fix this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of ES6. Because ES6 is gorgeous.

```
requests
  .filter(x => x.id > 50)
  .map(({id, start, end}) => ({id, start, end}))
```